# An unwanted attachment comes when mail is opened only in outlook via SMTP library

Tags: ios, outlook, smtp

When i send email using SMTP classes i get an untitled attachmentt when i open the mail in outlook. This attachment does not come in other mail except in Outlook.

Here is the format:

`by mx.google.com with ESMTPSA id zv3sm87988681pab.20.2014.05.28.05.01.34
for <multiple recipients>
(version=TLSv1.2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA bits=128/128);
Wed, 28 May 2014 05:01:36 -0700 (PDT)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
d=gmail.com; s=20120113;
h=date:message-id:from:to:content-type:mime-version:subject;
bh=PgZzyEIzglPFfZsphJX1BrHG0bPbP9AXqR++d0Gj8Oo=;
b=l2bri26it0L8RjTFANJYAPoHTCElx3T7r+ycMhOXj28vR9j9vxrGv+ZPvjoWybO1wd
zS11DajkWoKY1jKvUrJ70tfx5CqNtFs5kb5UnUwEm12ODn+x6eWVKt7mbPWn8SWB980R
OFRROKEP4PU5CG56leP9eAhy1nl09rtlC1XOt+2QyEHBmSOx1TE62qWPLvTmMvX89k9S
/Yu9icFRcALtyTSfN+jWe8v8qcPmhNnDxkD+jutPJk3Fv1Cp6zBKcrrjl+xBmxgW7ORQ
sZWf3RXKD5rYon3woCdb3zX+BUgRyloQSbHq/yZ8Z3J1KVQ5+NW9N5otvXepcr74kQyc
wxbg==
X-Received: by 10.68.201.10 with SMTP id jw10mr45530284pbc.25.140127849xxxx;
Wed, 28 May 2014 05:01:37 -0700 (PDT)
Date: Wed, 28 May 2014 17:31:36 +0530
Message-id: <testemail@gmail.com>
From: testemail@gmail.com
To: test@gmail.com
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=SKPSMTPMessage--Separator--Delimiter
Mime-Version: 1.0 (SKPSMTPMessage 1.0)
Subject: testing
X-ZohoMail: SS_6 SFPD SFPP UW2468 UB6248 FMWL SFP_WHTLST COSF SGR3_1_03044_351
X-ZohoMail-Owner: <testemail@gmail.com>
X-ZohoMail-Sender: xx.140.153.xxx
X-Zoho-Virus-Status: 2`

Code

```
NSDictionary *plainMsg = [NSDictionary
                              dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"text/html",kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,
                              messageBody,kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,@"8bit",kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,nil];
    emailMessage.parts = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:plainMsg,nil];

    [parts addObject:plainMsg];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what is in that attachment? What is the full MIME source of the message that you are sending?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko text/html is the MIME type. I am not sending any attachment via code. In other emails except outlook i am not getting that unwanted attachment.

Comment: Again, what is the complete MIME message? If you are not sending any attachments and only set the plain text and HTML parts, shouldn't the content type be multipart/alternative instead of multipart/mixed?